# inner text of element passed as <span onclick=foo(this) >myText</span>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML:**

`<span onclick="foo(this);" >myText</span>`

and in my **JavaScript** function I need to get innerText of this span element.

```
 function foo(parameter) {
             alert($(parameter).text);                       
         }
```

it always returns undefined.
I have tried innerHTML, textContent etc but nothing is helping me out.

Comment: text is a method `.text()`

Comment: If it is saying that `foo` is undefined, then the script needs to be loaded before the span is loaded.  Be specific about WHAT is undefined and that will help us help you.

Comment: alert gives undefined not foo is undefined.  and I have used .text as function too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `text` as function because it's actually jQuery function.

```
function foo(parameter) {
         alert($(parameter).text());                       
     }
```

or via raw JavaScript

```
function foo(parameter) {
         alert(parameter.textContent);                       
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using jQuery, so use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
function foo(parameter) {
    alert($(parameter).html());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**USING JQUERY**

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/jsbfn9rk/)

You can use `html()` function of jQuery. You should rewrite your Javascript as below

```
function foo(parameter) {
    alert($(parameter).html());
}
```

Please read more about `html()` in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

**USING JAVASCRIPT**

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/jsbfn9rk/1/)

Using pure javascript, it can be done as follows. You should be using `innerHTML` for that.

```
function foo(parameter) {
    alert(parameter.innerHTML);
}
```

Please read more about `innerHTML` in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)